# Is it okay to delete tags off of questions that the tags were created for if the tags will likely not become relevant?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

When going to the new tags page (a common place for me to look for tags to edit), lots of tags are vague and have been created on questions. **Is it considered okay to edit these questions for the purpose of deleting those tags, so that unneeded or blank tags that have no real reference do not clutter up the site?**

Comment: I'm not sure quite what kind of scenario you are thinking of.  Could you provide an example or two of questions where this might be appropriate?

Comment: Questions with bad tags should be edited to remove the bad tag(s), yes, but you have to be confident that the tag is truly a bad one according to the standards of the site. Can you provide some examples of tags you are thinking of deleting?

Comment: Ultimately it's pretty hard to argue with work tags; we even have some for non-SF works (<grumble>) like "scrooge-mcduck."  The problematic tags are the descriptive but non-categorizational tags like "entropy."

Comment: You've created a worthless tag for this question and I've removed it. Like that, you mean?

Comment: @Valorum He didn't create any tags for this question - if you'd checked before making a snide remark, you'd see that all the tags on this meta question were pre-existing tags and are [still used on other questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-blacklist-request).